# jQuery Mobile component for very large lists?

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I need to display very big lists of items, it can be up to a 10,000 items. I've done some tests with the listview component with Chrome on my computer but it takes a while to display the list, so will probably be even worse on a mobile.

So I'm looking for a component that allows displaying very large lists. Either by only loading the items that are currently visible, or by pagination or similar. Or perhaps JQM built-in listviews can be customized for this? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully used the [jquery.mobile.lazyloader](http://dcarrith.github.com/jquery.mobile.lazyloader/) on a previous project. I had fairly simple data and could just use the [json2html](http://json2html.com/) template option, although there is support for other templating libraries. I did find it to be a fairly complex plugin, however there are some good examples to follow on the aforementioned site.